# Java XOR operation

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

I came across this problem wherein all of the program was given barring only a piece of logic. What could be filled in the following problem's missing lines?

## Problem Statement

Jack and Daniel are friends. 
They want to encrypt their conversation so that they can save themselves from interception by a detective agency. So they invent a new cipher. 
Every message is encoded to its binary representation *B* of length *N*. 
Then it is written down *K* times, shifted by *0,1,...,K−1* bits. 
If *B=1001010* and *K=4* it looks like:

```
1001010
 1001010
  1001010
   1001010
```

Then calculate XOR in every column and write it down. This number is called *S*. For example, XOR-ing the numbers in the above example results in

```
1110100110
```

Then the encoded message *S* and *K* are sent to Daniel.

Jack is using this encoding algorithm and asks Daniel to implement a decoding algorithm. Can you help Daniel implement this?

### Input Format

- The first line contains two integers *N* and *K*.
- The second line contains string *S* of length *N+K−1* consisting of ones and  zeros.

### Output Format

Decoded message of length *N*, consisting of ones and zeros.

### Constraints

- 1≤N≤10^6,
- 1≤K≤10^6
- |S|=N+K−1
- It is guaranteed that *S* is correct.

### Sample Input#00

```
   7 4
   1110100110
```

### Sample Output#00

```
   1001010
```

### Sample Input#01

```
   6 2
   1110001
```

### Sample Output#01

```
   101111
```

### Explanation for Input#00

```
1001010
 1001010
  1001010
   1001010
----------
1110100110
```

### Explainatin for Input#01

```
101111
 101111
-------
1110001
```

---

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void solve(Input in, PrintWriter out) throws IOException {
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int k = in.nextInt();
        char[] c = in.next().toCharArray();
        int x = 0;
        char[] ans = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            ans[i] = (char) (((c[i] - '0') ^ x) + '0');// I understand we are converting the character into integer (c[i] - '0') then xoring it with x which is holding 0 and then again adding '0' to convert back it into character.
            x ^= ans[i] - '0';// But why are we doing this!!. From this line onward things are not clear.
            if (i >= k - 1) {
                ****FILL THE MISSING LINE HERE****

            }
        }
        out.println(ans);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        solve(new Input(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))), out);
        out.close();
    }

    static class Input {
        BufferedReader in;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        public Input(BufferedReader in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public Input(String s) {
            this.in = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s));
        }

        public String next() throws IOException {
            sb.setLength(0);
            while (true) {
                int c = in.read();
                if (c == -1) {
                    return null;
                }
                if (" \n\r\t".indexOf(c) == -1) {
                    sb.append((char)c);
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (true) {
                int c = in.read();
                if (c == -1 || " \n\r\t".indexOf(c) != -1) {
                    break;
                }
                sb.append((char)c);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public int nextInt() throws IOException {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }

        public long nextLong() throws IOException {
            return Long.parseLong(next());
        }

        public double nextDouble() throws IOException {
            return Double.parseDouble(next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This is *homework*? SO is not meant for homework...

Comment: Oh no! its a puzzle. I am trying to solve https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/magiclines/challenges/cipher-fill-the-key-line.

Comment: @JohnDoe: is this a contest that is currently taking place? I think it's a bit cheating to solve challenges with the help of the SO community. After the contest is finished, you can ask for a solution I think.

Comment: Contest is over 6 hrs ago. I could not solve it then,

Comment: @JohnDoe stay - i'm having an idea

Comment: sir, lol. i'm no sir. i'm 16 :3

Comment: And I 20 Sir, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: *please read the explenation, simply solving challenges by copy-pasting the answer is not useful.*

The constraint you can exploit is that

> *The first bit is untouched by the encryption algorithm*.

Indeed because all "masks" are shifted at least one to the right. So you can assume that the first bit of the encrypted part is the first bit of the decrypted content as well.

Now that you know the first bit, you can easily reconstruct the second bit, since it is only *xor*-ed with the first one we already know. So know we can calculate the second.

The third bit is xor-ed with the first and the second, so what one basically does is maintain a value that is the xor of all already obtained values and xor this with the next value. Intially the value is zero.

**Example**:

Take the first sample input:

```
1110100110
```

We can derive the first bit is a `1`. So now we know that the mask for the second bit is of the form:

```
       1110100110
mask    1????????
result 10
```

Now we know that the mask for the third bit is the xor of `1` and `0` thus `1`.

```
       1110100110
mask    11???????
result 100
```

iteratively this will eventually result in:

```
index      0123456789       
data       1110100110
submasks    1001010
             1001010
              1001010
mask       0111??????
result     1001??????
```

Now after `k-1` iterations, one no longer has an additional submask, indeed: one only writes `k` times the data one for the result, and `k-1` times the submask. So now we don't xor over new data anymore: we only xor the last `k` bits of the result, this can be done by *unxoring* (or simply *xoring*) of the bit of the result `k` positions to the left.

For the next mask, we thus *xor* our state (last bit of the mask) with both the last bit of the result (`1`) and the first bit of the result (`1`) which means the state remains the same (`1`):

```
index      0123456789
data       1110100110
submasks    1001010
             1001010
              1001010
mask       01111?????
result     10010?????
```

Now we xor with the last result bit (`0`) and the second result bit (`0`):

```
index      0123456789
data       1110100110
submasks    1001010
             1001010
              1001010
mask       011111????
result     100101????
```

For the next, we xor with the last (`1`) and the third (`0`) thus we swap the state. By keep doing this process, we eventually end with:

```
index      0123456789
data       1110100110
submasks    1001010
             1001010
              1001010
mask       0111110???
result     1001010???
```

Now we are no longer interested in the remaining bits so we terminate.

**What must be modified?**

In the `if`-part, we need to *xor* (`^`) with the `i-(k-1)`-th bit as well:

```
if (i >= k - 1) {
    x ^= ans[i-(k-1)] - '0';
}
```

Comment: Precisely. You got there before me :D

Comment: This kind of investigation into the problem is what I wanted, hence I am accepting it. I know my education was not on perfect lines and I tend to use StackOverflow to fill the lacunae. But I am not going to apologize for that.

Comment: @JohnDoe StackOverflow is always there to help :)

Comment: @JohnDoe `education … lacunae` which apparently have not been with dead languages.

Comment: :) , I was getting close votes, for this question. But I came to know a lot after CommuSoft answer, I was thinking about it, I had some idea about it.  It was vague at best. It was only after the answer I was quite clear about it. Yeah trying to fill the lacunae ....

Comment: The weird thing is that the close votes are about *unclear what you're asking* (didn't close vote btw). With the problem statement, it is quite clear what you're asking. A perhaps more valid reason was that it was off-topic because it is a challenge/puzzle/... I'm glad this answer was contributing...